# Sphinx: how to cross-reference a target generated by a custom directive

Tags: python, python-sphinx, cross-reference, docutils

I'm having trouble cross-referencing a section generated by a custom directive.

Here is the directive:

```py
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers import rst


class TestDirective(rst.Directive):

    has_content = False
    required_arguments = 1
    option_spec = {}

    def run(self):
        my_arg = self.arguments[0]

        target_node = nodes.target('', '', refid=nodes.make_id(my_arg))
        section = nodes.section(
            '',
            nodes.title(text=my_arg),
            ids=[nodes.make_id(my_arg)],
            names=[nodes.fully_normalize_name(my_arg)])

        return [target_node, section]


def setup(app):
   app.add_directive('mytest', TestDirective)
```

And here is how it's used:

```
=============
Test document
=============

.. mytest:: section1

Section 1 content.


.. _section2:

section2
========

Section 2 content.
```

Now, the following works only for `section2`:

```
Here are links to :ref:`section1` and :ref:`section2`.
```

The link is only generated properly for `section2` and I get the following error:

```
test.rst:19: WARNING: undefined label: section1 (if the link has no caption the
label must precede a section header)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: I would like to ask where you read the API defining `from docutils.parsers import rst`? I tried looking into this, and got the code running to some extent, but without a documented API I looked into the docutils source code and couldn't find the time to try and make sense to it all. If you can recommend something easing that part of the research I might try again.

Comment: @bad_coder: well, from the [Sphinx tutorial](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/extdev/tutorial.html#the-directive-classes) actually

Comment: @bad_coder: ok!

Comment: @abey I answered my own post. You may find it useful. This is torture. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64146870/generating-labels-for-nodes-of-a-custom-directive

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing the function of a reference label versus a directive.

To get the terminology clear, in your markup:

- The part which worked has a [reference label](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-arbitrary-locations) (`.. _section2:`) directly before a [section title](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#sections) ("`section2`" with adornment underline).  That provides a target which can be linked to via an [interpreted text role](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-syntax) (`` :ref:`section2` ``).  That's regular Sphinx boilerplate.
- The part which doesn't work has your custom directive (`.. mytest::`) with its single required argument (`section1`) and no content block (there is no indented text following the directive).
- The line "`Section 1 content.`" is a stand-alone paragraph.

Maybe you wanted a custom interpreted text role to provide special functionality, or a `roles.XRefRole` subclass, or the [autosectionlabel extension](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosectionlabel.html)?

---

EDIT

The `:ref:` role is for arbitrary locations ("labels", whatever that means)
but you can also cross-reference to custom objects via `:any:` [once it is registered](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_object_type):

```
def setup(app):
    app.add_directive('mytest', TestDirective)

    app.add_object_type(
        directivename='mytest',
        rolename='banana',
    )
```

then ReST content:

```
See :any:`section1` which is a TestDirective.

Or also works via the rolename :banana:`section1`.
```

[Many would agree](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/6659) that all this functionality is poorly documented.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I've got the terminology right. My question is: how to generate a "section title" paired with a matching "reference label" from a custom directive (if that's possible at all)?

Comment: I am trying to do this exact same thing. Beating my head against the wall.

Comment: @natersoz: let me know if you find anything!

Comment: I did not find abey's question in my serching - and wrote my own question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64146870/generating-labels-for-nodes-of-a-custom-directive This contains project code which attempts the same thing the OP is asking with an small example project on github using the todo directive (link is in the question).

Comment: The directive creates a reference which can be accessed within the directive, but cannot be referenced from .rst files. If I understand abbey's question then we are asking the same thing.