# Generating labels for nodes of a custom directive

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils

Using the [Sphinx "TODO" Directive example](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/tutorials/todo.html) I would like to reference the `todo` instances embedded within a .rst file. For example, if the .rst file content contains:

```
.. todo:: foo

.. todo:: bar
```

I can see that the following code (taken from the Sphinx TODO example page)

```py
class TodoDirective(SphinxDirective):

    # this enables content in the directive
    has_content = True

    def run(self):
        targetid = 'todo-%d' % self.env.new_serialno('todo')
        targetnode = nodes.target('', '', ids=[targetid])

        todo_node = todo('\n'.join(self.content))
        todo_node += nodes.title(_('Todo'), _('Todo'))
        self.state.nested_parse(self.content, self.content_offset, todo_node)

        if not hasattr(self.env, 'todo_all_todos'):
            self.env.todo_all_todos = []

        self.env.todo_all_todos.append({
            'docname': self.env.docname,
            'lineno': self.lineno,
            'todo': todo_node.deepcopy(),
            'target': targetnode,
        })

        return [targetnode, todo_node]
```

Creates target nodes with `ids`: `todo-0` and `todo-1`.
That are successfully referenced by embedding the directive in a .rst file as:

```
.. todolist::
```

What I would like to do is reference the `todo` items within a .rst file like this:

```
:ref:`todo-0`
:ref:`todo-1`
```

This would require getting the `TodoDirective` to generate a label for each target node. I have not been able to figure out how to do so.

This simple project is posted here: https://github.com/natersoz/sphinx_sandbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem as you and was able to resolve the issue by looking at the [autosectionlabel](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/3.x/sphinx/ext/autosectionlabel.py#L36) extension.

What they do there is to add the reference to the labels domain data. I got it working inside a custom directive like so:

```
nodeId = nodes.make_id("some-id")
self.env.app.env.domaindata["std"]["labels"][nodeId] = self.env.docname, nodeId, "Title"
section = nodes.section(ids=[nodeId])
section.append(nodes.title(text="Title"))
```

Key is the second line of the code above.

Also you want to add the label to the `anonlabels` to be able to reference it via

```
:ref:`foo <nodeId>`
```

like so:

```
self.env.app.env.domaindata["std"]["anonlabels"][nodeId] = self.env.docname, nodeId
```

Comment: Thanks - I *almost* have this working. Have to task switch out and might take me some time to get back to it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I found one way to perform this operation. It likely only works for HTML output:

```
`Text related to todo-0 <introduction.html#todo-0>`_
```

This reference link will successfully link to the TODO.
All other reference attempts fail. i.e. These all fail:

```
Note: these syntaxes do not work::

    `introduction.html#todo-1`_

    :ref:`introduction.html#todo-1`

    :ref:`todo-1`
```